# Sum up Multiple Columns if Column 'A' is identical

Tags: vba, excel

After some time searching for usable code, I've found this to check if the value in Column A is identical. If so it sums up whatever is in the Column G.
Than it deletes all other Columns.

Now I need Code able to keep the Columns A to E and sum up the values from F to I.

Code:

```
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim Dic As Variant
Dim arr As Variant
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Range("A2:I10000").Select
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
arr = WorkRng.Value
For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
    Dic(arr(i, 1)) = Dic(arr(i, 1)) + arr(i, 7)
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
WorkRng.ClearContents
WorkRng.Range("A1").Resize(Dic.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Dic.keys)
WorkRng.Range("G1").Resize(Dic.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Dic.items)
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Is someone able to tell me what the code does and what I have to implement to get it working like I need to? It would be nice if someone would just post the code I need but i want to understand and learn from it.

Current, simplyfied Table:
Name      Category  Visits Shared
Project 1    Cat1       1      1
Project 2    Cat1       1      1
Project 3    Cat2       1      1
Project 1    Cat1       1      1
Project 3    Cat2       1      1

What i need:
Name      Category  Visits Shared
Project 1    Cat1       2      2
Project 2    Cat1       1      1
Project 3    Cat2       2      2

Comment: Why not use a pivot table?

Comment: @SJR I've tried to do it with a pivot table, but it looked very awkward and didnt sum up the parts I wanted/needed (summing up dates that should have been untouched etc.) Thats why I started searching for a script-based solution for the problem

Comment: Why don't you add a column that is the sum of column F to I and then do a pivot table on that? If you don't like the format you can always adjust it or even replace it with values afterwards. In your current code you probably need to create a new array with columns A-E data and summed F-I. Plenty of examples online for you to make a start.

Comment: @SJR So What do i have to do with the Code above to get it working. Im not able to sum up the values from F-I as i need the values to be, of course, seperated from each other. its a statistic table merged from many sheets in the workbook and with the code i want to get the summary out of it.

Comment: Why "of course", nobody here knows what you are doing? I suggest you read up on how this place works [ask].

Comment: @SJR I'm sorry if it sounded harsh, but if I add up all the columns in another column, why should i even seperate the values into different columns.

Comment: Eh? Not harsh, I am just spelling out that you are unlikely to get someone here to write your code from scratch as it's now how it generally works. You will have to show some effort. I don't follow your question I'm afraid - I thought your values were in different columns.

Comment: Read up on pivot tables (or even Subtotals). You should be able to do what you need without a macro. Pivot tables are not easy if you don't understand them, but it is not a steep learning curve - give it 30 minutes, and you'll get it.

Comment: @vacip Is there any way in pivot tables to fill multiple columns with text (I've edited the question with an example of what im looking for, is this possible with pivot tables?)

Comment: @YowE3K After Executing the VBA, all duplicates are gone and the values of the column G are summed up from the rows, where the text of a was identical. but B,C,D,E,F,H and I are empty now, so the values/text in there was deleted as well. i just want to more or less fix this and not just add up g, but F, H and I as well.

Comment: Yes it is possible with a pivot table, that is what pivot tables are for. But like I said, you would need to spend 30 minutes learning pivot tables...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the comments in this. This generates the output from your input

```
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim Dic As Object
Dim arr As Variant, tmp As Variant
Dim ProjCat As String, xTitleID As String
Dim i As Long
Dim Key

xTitleID = "KutoolsforExcel"
Range("A2:I10000").Select

Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleID, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)

arr = WorkRng.Value2

Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
    ' Use a combination key of Name and Category
    ProjCat = arr(i, 1) & "//" & arr(i, 2)
    ' Handle empty values in range
    If Not ProjCat = "//" Then
        If Not Dic.exists(ProjCat) Then
            ' Create empty array for dictionary Item
            ReDim tmp(1 To 2)
            Dic.Add Key:=ProjCat, Item:=tmp
        End If
        ' Set Dictionary item to variable
        tmp = Dic(ProjCat)
        ' Update array with new values
        ' You may need to change these for your columns (assuming they're in columns G and H)
        tmp(1) = tmp(1) + arr(i, 7)
        tmp(2) = tmp(2) + arr(i, 8)
        ' Store array back in dictionary
        Dic(ProjCat) = tmp
    End If
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With WorkRng
    .ClearContents
    ' Write back dictionary
    i = 0
    For Each Key In Dic.keys
        i = i + 1
        ' Split the key back into two individual values
        .Range("A" & i).Resize(1, 2) = Split(Key, "//")
        ' Write back results
        .Range("G" & i).Resize(1, 2) = Dic(Key)
    Next Key
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: First off all thanks for the comments in your code, i've got it working for my layout now except of 1 tiny thing. in column D is a Date, which, after your code gets converted into a number and i cant format it back to a date, do you have a solution for this as well, it would help me very much

Comment: The array takes all the data as value2. This will use the date as a long value. It should just need to be formatted (unless you’re doing something else to it as well)

Answer (score 1):

Not really a proper answer, but did this with a pivot table and adjusting the layout a bit.

[image]